# Execute PHP script inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

This is my PHP page:

```
<div class="whomfollow">
        <div class="umayknow">People you may know</div>
      <ul>
      <?php
            $result = $linkID1->query("select ud.UserID,ud.Name,ud.Company,ud.Designation,ud.UserType,up.ProfilePic from user_details ud join user_picture up on ud.UserID=up.UserID where ud.UserID!='$UserID' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20")
            or
            die(mysqli_error());

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $UT1='';
                if($row['UserType']=='A')
                {
                    $UT1='Advertiser';
                }
                else if($row['UserType']=='P')
                {
                    $UT1='Publisher';
                }
        ?>
        <li class="postimage followimgconnections">
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="#"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$row['ProfilePic']." />"; ?></a></div>
            <div class="pull-left followboxcontent">
              <div><a href="#"><b><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></b></a></div>
              <div><a class="followsmall_content" href="#"><?php echo $UT1." - ".$row['Designation']." - ".$row['Company']; ?></a></div>
              <div class="followbtn"><button id="myBtn" onClick="connect(<?php echo $row[UserID]; ?>)">Connect</button></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">

        <p class="popupheading">Invitation Sent</p>
        <p class="popupcontent">Your invitation is on its way.</p>
        <div class="invidone"><a href="#" class="close">Done</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script>
function connect(num) {
    var x = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    <?php
        $ID=num;
        $stts='IS';  //Invitation Sent
        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("insert into user_connections set MyUserID=?, MyFriendsUserID=?, cstatus=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $UserID,$ID,$stts);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    ?>
    modal.style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

Now as soon as the page is loaded, the PHP part inside the JavaScript is executed automatically, I want to run that PHP part when the JavaScript is called. If it's not possible to do it this way, then is there another way?

Comment: You need to use AJAX.

Comment: "Now as soon as the page is loaded, the php part inside the javascript is executed automatically". No, it isn't. Browsers cannot execute PHP. The PHP part is executed _on the server_, _before_ the page is even sent to the browser to be loaded. PHP runs on the server. The execution of the PHP is part of the process of creating the content which the browser receives, and any output from it is included as static content in the page which the browser finally receives and renders to the user. If you want to execute a PHP function during the lifetime of the page, without refreshing, you need ajax.

Comment: All PHP is always running on the server, javascript is running on the client. You can call php from the javascript using an Ajax request

Comment: @panther.........can u pls help me out with the ajax script. It will be a great help

Comment: ...an ajax call makes another separate HTTP request to the server, which executes a specific PHP script at the URL that you specify in the ajax request. Any generated response from that is then returned to the browser asynchronously once it finishes, and can be seen and processed by a JavaScript callback. You can google lots of examples of how to use ajax - hundreds and hundreds. Take a tutorial, make an attempt to apply that to your own requirements, and then come back here if you encounter a specific problem. No point in us re-inventing the wheel and producing yet another identical how-to.

Comment: php is serever side scripting language. So your php code will be executed on server. You can make AJAX call for that.

Comment: ...you really need to get the basic idea of client/server, and how HTTP requests and the web work in general, before going any further. Otherwise you'll constantly tie yourself in conceptual knots like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, used AJAX and solved the problem.

```
function connect(num) {
var x = document.getElementById('myBtn');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "request-connect.php?id="+num
})

modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: aammm.... what is the difference/benefit with my answer ? ) You just pass param ID via GET query and use type "POST" meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function connect(num) {
var x = document.getElementById('myBtn');

$.post('/Script.php', {id: num});

modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Script.php:

```
    $ID=$_POST['id'];
    $stts='IS';  //Invitation Sent
    $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("insert into user_connections set MyUserID=?, MyFriendsUserID=?, cstatus=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $UserID,$ID,$stts);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```